# How do I convert std::ffi::OsString to f64 or f32

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I am grabbing the second argument with a function and would like to convert it from a std::ffi:OsString to a float or a double. I currently have the following code but the parse doesn't work.

```
fn get_second_arg() -> Result<f64, Box<dyn Error>> {
    match env::args_os().nth(2) {
        None => Err(From::from("expected 2 arguments")),
        Some(min_balance) =>  {
            let min_balance_f64: f64 = min_balance.parse()?
            Ok(min_balance_f64)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
no method named `parse` found for struct `std::ffi::OsString` in the current scope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ffi::OsString` has a member `into_string` that returns `Result<String, OsString>`, in which you can extract the `Ok` variant and call `String::parse`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness this is the working code of @Braddy Dean's answer:

```
fn get_second_arg() -> Result<f64, Box<dyn Error>> {
    match env::args_os().nth(2) {
        None => Err(From::from("expected 2 arguments")),
        Some(min_balance) =>  {
            let min_balance_option = min_balance.into_string().ok();
            match min_balance_option {
                None => Err(From::from("Unable to parse second argument")),
                Some (value) => {
                    let min_balance_f64: f64 = value.parse()?;
                     Ok(min_balance_f64)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```